# extjs options.params...what is it for?

Tags: extjs

Can some one please explain the options.params parameter for an ext js grid? I am unable to figure it out from the documentation.
Please let me know how I can help by providing more details as necessary

Comment: DOn't you mean `options.params` object that is passed to callback in `Ext.Ajax.request()`?

Comment: I am a newbie so pls pardon me. What I am seeking is when I do Ext.apply(options.params, params) on clietn side, how do i retrieve the param values on server side (java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do seem to be quite lost. Refer to the [ExtJS FAQ](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ): and in particular to [Gird FAQ](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ_Grid).
Ext.apply has nothing to do with sending stuff to the server, it simply copies properties from one object to another.  In order to use grids with data from/to the server you need to master the concepts of Stores and Readers.  To load data is quite simple, you simply call the grid's store load method (e.g. g`rid.getStore().load();`).  To send the data on a grid to the server is a bit more complex... I think you will be better off in [Ext's forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/).